# Are there keyboard shortcuts to scroll to the top and bottom of a document?

Tags: macos, macbook

I'm using a Macbook and want to scroll to the top and bottom of documents using the keyboard. Is there a keyboard shortcut that does this?

Comment: What is the application you're using to display the document?

Comment: Danny, you've not made it 100% clear and as such makes it very difficult to answer; Can you please make it really clear if this is for any document, or only for web pages / only Word Processing / only Databases etc? -1

Comment: @DaveRook "Document windows" are a standard nomenclature on OS X, and scrolling to the top or bottom of those usually works with the keys Dennis mentions below, not even in those, but all kinds of apps. I agree the question seems vague but it's not really…

Answer (score 95):

On a Macbook, try <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>◄</kbd> (function + left arrow) for Home and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>►</kbd> (function + right arrow) for End.

Comment: This only works in some apps.

Comment: And this only moves focus, not cursor.

Comment: For the PDF docs, it goes fine as mentioned in the answer. In case of the MS Docs file, you may use `CMD+ fn+ LeftArrow/ RigthArrow`.

Comment: In finder.app, in a folder with many files, fn+→ scrolls slowly to the bottom with lag and cmd+fn+→ scrolls instantly. Go figure.

Answer (score 40):

Sure. Just use <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd>. The <kbd>cmd</kbd> key is to either side of the spacebar.

Comment: everyone says that but that does not work. I don't know why but i have tried it many times

Comment: Command-up Command-down works on my Macbook, make sure that the page is in focus and not a text area or box. Click on some "white space" then try cmd-up and cmd-down.

Comment: That only works in browsers. In Finder cmd+up is to navigate to parent folder and cmd+down is to navigate into a folder or open a document.

Comment: This works (e.g. in Sublime).

Comment: works in VS Code

Comment: @danny I can feel your pain getting such answers ;)

Comment: Works in the native Mac TextEdit app.

Answer (score 16):

If you hold <kbd>fn</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd> at the same time, then hit <kbd>◄</kbd> (left arrow) for scroll to top or <kbd>►</kbd> (right arrow) for scroll to bottom, that should do it.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Just try it on this very web page in Safari. It will not navigate the web page, but go to the home page (`Command-Home`) or do nothing (`Command-End`). In TextEdit, it will just produce the notification sound for unassigned keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: It at least works for Office/Word, which is what one may assume is meant by "Document."

Comment: Doesn't work in Pages though, so this seems to be specific to Microsoft programs on OS X.

Comment: That's the right answer. @DanielBeck - Navigating on web pages inside the browser is different from navigating in Finder or Word, what I think is the question here.

Comment: @koivo [Pages](http://www.apple.com/mac/pages/) is the word processor from Apple.

Comment: @DanielBeck - Please see my proper answer below.

Comment: works for intellij

Comment: It's flat out awful that there's no system wide shortcut for this.

Comment: This is the correct answer for iTerm2

Answer (score 7):

For clarification, this question must be answered twice:

**1. For internet browsers (FF, Safari, Chrome, ...), but also for Apple's Pages it's**

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>▼</kbd> for jumping to bottom and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>▲</kbd> for jumping back to top.

**2. For Finder, and also for Microsoft Word it's**

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>►</kbd> for jumping to bottom and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>◄</kbd> for jumping back to top.

Notice: The shorcuts from 1. will work in Finder, too. When you hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>▼</kbd> in Finder you'll open the selected folder or document (same as <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, O for Open). When you hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>▲</kbd> in Finder you'll be navigated to the parent folder. With these two you are able to quiete easily navigate in Finder with just keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hold down <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd> simultaneously; then to go to the beginning of the document, press the <kbd>Up</kbd> cursor as well, while to go to the end of the doc press NOT down, but <kbd>Right</kbd> cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Try with: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd>/<kbd>right arrow</kbd>.
Worked for me.

Comment: That one is the right answer, understanding that the OP wanted to navigate inside documents and not on web pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a website, holding down FN and Left Arrow at the same time takes you to the top.  If you are in MS Word for Mac, hold down FN  Command and Left Arrow to take you to the top.  FN Right Arrow to go to bottom if on a website.  FN Command Right Arrow to go to bottom on MS Word for Mac.

Comment: This is the same information already in multiple other answers here. While this question doesn't have a selected answer, it is still best to stick to answers where the information you have to give a) answers the question and b) has not already been provided.

Answer (score -1):

Just hold <kbd>spacebar</kbd> to scroll down and hold <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>spacebar</kbd> to scroll up.

Comment: How would this work in a word processing document?

Answer (score -1):

Use BetterTouch tool. I made a really useful shortcut fn + two finger scroll up as END and fn + two finger scroll down as HOME

Comment: Please see [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/354511) In particular, how would somebody use this tool to solve this problem? You say, "I made a really useful shortcut ...." Don't we need to know what you defined the shortcut to be?